# Calling Visual Studio's link.exe from Matlab fails

Tags: visual-studio-2010, matlab, mex

For *custom mex file building* within Matlab, I am trying to call Visual Studio 2010's link.exe from a Matlab command shell via:

```
>> !link
```

to no effect at all. Alternative calls with Matlab's 'dos' return an error value:

```
>> dos('link')
   ans = -1.0737e9
```

Calling the link executable directly from an external Windows shell, however, works perfectly well.

How can I call the **link.exe** from within Matlab? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

- OS: Win7 32bit
- Matlab: R2012a
- Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express

Thx, Peter

Comment: I suggest reading through [these docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/building-mex-files.html) about how to build `mex` files, I've never had to do anything other than what the instructions say to do in order to get it to work right.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are returning correct values in source code of link.exe.

Both dos('testapp.exe') and system('testapp.exe') should work... If you elaborate the problem (input & output to link.exe) someone may be able to help you.